# How do I send data to my server from sim800 / sim900 using MQTT protocol

Tags: mqtt, gsm, arduino-uno, sim900, thingsboard

I have been trying since past few days to connect my sim800 module with Arduino to send data to server.

I have been referencing this library : https://github.com/elementzonline/SIM800_MQTT

However, when run, it simply gets out of the loop after printing 'AT' command only. I have not been able to run more than that using this library.
Does anyone have a working code / sample which I can reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After short discussion on Thingsboard forum I would like to summarize solution here:

1) We recommend to use [TinyGSM](https://github.com/vshymanskyy/TinyGSM) library

2) The person who answer this question was able to publish working code on [github](https://github.com/KudosAbhay/Sending_Data_To_Thingsboard). Thanks, Abhay!

Comment: That program is not based on MQTT @Andrew. Anyways, thanks for the answer for TinyGSM library. I will look into that.